# Remote Desktop through lan cable

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, lan, desktop

What are the proper steps to connect via Remote Desktop Connection using only a LAN. The OS of machine A would be Windows XP and machine B would be Windows 7.

I would like to remotely connect to machine A from machine B.

What would be the first step and so on.

Comment: Get them talking to eachother on a network, and then type the IP address into RDC. Simple as that!

Comment: @Raj - Purchase a router with 2 Lan ports.  Assigned different ip addresses to each connected computer.  Connect to said ip address.

Comment: @Ramhound: One doesn't need a router for this – a switch would be enough, and even that is not necessary with a relatively modern network card.

Comment: @grawity - A switch requires more technical knowlege to setup.   A router will work out of the box.

Comment: @Ramhound: What setup does it need aside from plugging in the cables and waiting for the systems to choose their Zeroconf IP addresses?

Comment: @grawity - My experience is having to configure myself the intranet ip address for each client instead of allowing hardware to automatically assign the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable remote desktop on the win7 computer.
2. Make sure both are on the same network (e.g. connect the LAN cable to the same hub or the same switch; configure the IP stack to use the same subnet.
3. [Start] [run] `mstsc.exe`
4. Type in the name or the IP of the windows 7 computer.

Done.

Comment: If you want to connect them together with just a cable, you need to make sure that the cable you have is a crossover cable, not just a regular cat5 LAN cable. 

Then you need to configure each computer with an IP address in the same range. Eg 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.20
Then they will be able to see each other

Comment: True. Though autoMDI/MDX is quite common these days (and is required on Gbit NICs), unless both computers are very old this should not be a problem).

Comment: @Steve N. Not anymore. Since many years, network cards are smart enough to do the cross-over by themselves, so a normal ethernet cable will do the job as well.